# Vote Early, Vote Often

Tags: discussion, voting

In order to help set a high base-level for voting, we need to get as many early votes in as we can. It should be everyone's goal to try to earn that Suffrage badge as soon as possible (without mindlessly giving out votes).

See this original post from the Tex SE meta site below (I personally think this should be a standard-issue post on every private beta meta):

https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often

Comment: Upvoted for truth ;)

Answer (score 7):

I agree, as long as users also remember to downvote **wrong** answers, flag me-too/comment answers and vote to close if something is just of poor quality.

But as long as you see something worthy of an upvote, leave one! :-)

Comment: I was under the impression downvotes count equally towards e.g. Suffrage (I could be wrong here)? Anyway, agree that we need to balance a high voting base level with quality.

Comment: @Greg, they do.

Answer (score 5):

Got my suffrage already! So vote, vote, vote all of y'all!

Btw Mr. Cartaino if you see this, I think the Vote Early, Vote Often post should be posted to every beta out there. It's one of the most valuable posts for any starting site.

Answer (score 5):

I've noticed downvotes being handed out quite liberally so far - hopefully not just people downvoting for the sake of voting. None the less, I've also earned my suffrage badge, and glad to see some good content coming to the fore.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Vote Vote Vote -- this SE needs it.